# Rearrange an arraay based on first array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays like this:

```
array1 = ["green", "blue", "red"];
array2 = ["green", "green", "red", "red", "green", "green", "blue", "red", "Blue"];
```

But I need an output like

```
output_array = ["green", "green", "green", "green", "blue", "Blue", "red", "red", "red"];
```

Comment: what about the sparse part? what have you tried?

Comment: What is even your algorithm? Are you trying to combine those arrays? Are you trying to sort `array2` after the scheme in `array1`? Please specify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort` alongside `indexOf`:

```js
const arr1 = ["green", "blue", "red"]
const arr2 = ["green", "green", "red", "red", "green", "green", "blue", "red", "blue"]

console.log(arr2.sort((a, b) => arr1.indexOf(a) - arr1.indexOf(b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you !

```
    array1=["green","red","blue"]; 
    array2=["green","green","red","red","green","green","blue","red","Blue"];

    const map = array2.reduce((acc, e) => acc.set(e, (acc.get(e) || 0) + 1), new Map());
    let result = array1.reduce((acc, a)=>  [...acc, ...Array(map.get(a)).fill(a)] , []);
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you mean alphabetically order, but you could merge both arrays and then sort the result:

```
let output_array = array1.concat(array2);

output_array.sort()
```